# How to defined data type for nested recursive data

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

I got a data from js side, it looks like this

`{
    "selectionSet": {
        "type": 1,
        "selections": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "viewer"
                },
                "selectionSet": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "selections": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "avatarUrl"
                            },
                            "selectionSet": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}`

I'm wondering how to defined types for `selectionSet` and `selections`.

It seems that when defining `selections`, I should have defined `selectionSet` because it has a field whose type is `selectionSet`. But when defined `selectionSet`, I should have defined `selections`

Can someone answer it in OCaml style? I want to convert this JSON style data into a record.

Comment: You are encouraged to post code as text, not as images. This helps people read and manipulate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define mutualy recursive types or functions for that matter you can use the key word `and`. In your case your records would look something like that:

```
type selectionSet = {
  t : t;
  selections : selections list;
}

and selections = {
  name : name;
  selectionSet : selectionSet option;
}
```